# Why can't I see installed AIR applications in /Applications on Mac OS Lion?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, adobe-air

Yesterday I did a clean install of **Mac OS Lion**, and installed bunch of apps, including **HipChat Desktop Application** (an **Adobe AIR app**). I used it for some time and eventually closed it.

Today I wanted to start it again, but couldn't find it in Launchpad. I looked in **/Applications** folder, but I couldn't find it there either (I still don't have ~/Applications).

I went back to HipChat website (from where I installed) and a Flash plugin allowed me to run the app immediately. It shows up in my Dock and if I "keep it" there, I can launch it again (it still doesn't appear in my /Applications dir). However, it asks me for confirmation about launching an app that has been downloaded from the Internet (every time I start it, it's annoying). I also see the app in Adobe AIR uninstaller.

I then went to my old Snow Leopard installation and found HipChat in my /Applications folder there. Copied it to the Lion disk and it works. Now I have two HipChat entries in Adobe AIR uninstaller.

I guess I solved the issue at hand, but I still don't understand where the original app is located and how I can access it and move it to Applications.

I couldn't find it anywhere with both Finder search nor `find` command in terminal (I used `$find / -name "HipChat*" -print`).

**So, how does Adobe AIR store the installed applications (on OSX Lion) and is there any way to get them to show up in Launchpad?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find out the location of an application in the Dock, hold down the <kbd>command ⌘</kbd> key and click (don't hold) on the icon. It will be revealed in Finder.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! :) Unfortunately I already fixed the problem by reinstalling Flash and AIR and the app now installs into the proper location. I'll mark this as accepted, but I can't actually verify if it would work for the problem at hand.